# How do I check if prettyPhoto is defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, prettyphoto

I have this snippet that is on my main js file that our entire site uses

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        theme: 'light_square',
        showTitle: false,
        allow_resize: true
    });
```

that problem is that on some pages prettyPhoto is undefined and causes an error in firebug so i thought i would try this

```
if(typeof prettyPhoto=="undefined"){
    //do nothing
}else{
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        theme: 'light_square',
        showTitle: false,
        allow_resize: true
    });
}
```

but this always executes to true, even on pages that prettyPhoto is available....any ideas

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
if (typeof $.fn.prettyPhoto == "function") {
    // we have prettyPhone on the page
}
```

Comment: You could even just do `if ($.fn.prettyPhoto)`, though it's a little looser.

Comment: What is the $.fn. and  can you use the $.fn. on most jquery elements to ensure they are available

Comment: `$.fn` is a jQuery function prototype, the place where all instance methods are defined (everything you use on *collections* of elements, like `$('p').text()`, `$('p').each()`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

if you do a console.log(prettyPhoto) on a page that you know has prettyPhoto, what does it say it is?  an object?

If so, then you do

```
if(typeof prettyPhoto === 'object'){
    //do your stuff here.
}
```